# How to dynamically pull the most recent file name to the script

Tags: vbscript

I have below script which removes extra space after comma (`,`). My requirement is as below.

To copy the most recent **FILENAME** to the myFile attribute as shown below. Can we change the below script to pull the most recent file instead of me putting manually?

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim filetxt
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const fmtUnicode = -1, fmtASCII = 0, fmtDefault = -2

Set re = New RegExp
Dim strInput
Dim Matches
Dim Match

Dim myFile
'change the following file path to point to your file
myFile = "\\dgggsym\g_t_t_t$\CDO_MTK_SMT\Business Performance Reporting\Hari krishna\csvtotab\usp_GO_CallDetailsByVqueue_2016-09-27.csv"

re.IgnoreCase = True

Set filetxt = objFSO.OpenTextFile(myFile, ForReading, False, fmtDefault)

Dim arrFileLines()
i = 0
Do Until filetxt.AtEndOfStream
  ReDim Preserve arrFileLines(i)
  arrFileLines(i) = filetxt.ReadLine

  strInput = arrFileLines(i)
  'WScript.Echo(strInput)

  re.Pattern = "\s"
  re.Global = True

  arrFileLines(i) = re.Replace(strInput, "")
  'WScript.Echo(arrFileLines(i))

  i = i + 1
Loop

filetxt.Close

Set filetxt = objFSO.OpenTextFile(myFile, ForWriting, False, fmtDefault)
For j = LBound(arrFileLines) To UBound(arrFileLines)
  filetxt.WriteLine(arrFileLines(j))
Next
filetxt.Close

Set filetxt = Nothing
```

Comment: *Can we change the below script to pull the most recent file instead of me putting manually?* Sure we can. Will we do it for you? Not very likely without seeing any effort on your part. What have you tried to solve this yourself? What were the results of your attempts? How were they different from what you expected? How do you identify the "most recent file" in the first place?

Comment: And to identify most recent path I have used below code which pulls the file   from source to the path given                                                       strSource = given my path
strDest = given my path
intDays = 1 --takes recent file ( 1 day )

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strSource)
On Error Resume Next
Set objFiles = objFolder.Files
dtmEarliestDate = DateAdd("d", -intDays, Now())
For Each objFile In objFiles
    If objFile.DateLastModified > CDate(dtmEarliestDate) Then
        objFSO.copyFile objFile, strDest

Comment: @KrishNa - if  you need to post more code, do so as an edit to your question, not as a comment. This will allow you to format the code so that it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the solution

I used below to get the filename to append to the path.

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b .') do set "recent=%%x"

and used !recent! to get the name.